# is <this.props.Component /> a correct syntax in React JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a strange case where I used code splitting within React SPA.

My code needs to render sometimes thin component, and in other cases a full component (for logged-in users).
now, `Component` has been sent to the class as part of props, and within render function I'm trying to render:

```
<this.props.Component />
```

and, here is the strange case. sometimes this line of code throws error:

`error Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined`

with stack trace that pointing to this line. In other cases it works perfectly.

Could anyone explain if this syntax is wrong? or maybe what causes it not to work sometimes?

Comment: Not knowing the rest of the component, I would expect the syntax to be something like `{this.props.Component}`.  Though if `this.props` might be undefined then you'd do `{this.props && this.props.Component}`.

Comment: no, `Component` in our case is a real class component. which I have to render like this: `<this.props.Component onClickHandler={this.onClick} />` etc. how would you do it with the syntax you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the correct answer is that this syntax is not allowed (as of React 16),
I still can't understand why it had worked for me,
but if someone needs to render a component based on props he gets, he has to do it this way (thanks to @David):

```
{this.props && this.props.Component({
    onClickHandler: this.onClick,
    currentUser: this.props.currentUser,
    etc..
  })}
```

and type of Component must be a function.

another option to whom may want to write pure JSX:

```
const { Component } = this.props

return (
      <Component
        currentUser={this.props.currentUser}
        onClickHandler={this.onClick />
)
```